# D3.js: Restrict the area where an object can be dragged on a map/projection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there any way of restricting the area where an object can be dragged to on a D3.js map?  In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gbazin/c5yykb9e/15), the user can drag the objects outside the projection boundaries, which is what I want to avoid.

Any idea?  Thanks!

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
    var x = d3.select(this).attr("x");
    var y = d3.select(this).attr("y");
    var dx = d3.event.x - x;
    var dy = d3.event.y - y;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")");
    });

function putCircle(x, y) {
    d3.select('svg')
        .append('path')
        .attr("class", "projected")
        .attr("x", x).attr("y", y)
        .datum(d3.geo.circle().origin(projection.invert([x, y])).angle(5))
        .attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
        .call(drag);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be easier methods, but I've used this method in resamping rasters based on projections.

First, for projections such as an orthographic projection, `projection.invert` will return valid geographic points for any svg point, regardless of whether or not it is within the apparent projection area.

Second, for projections such as Aitoff, `projection.invert` will return undefined for svg points that fall outside the projection area.

There are many projections that fall into each of these categories.

So, you will need to have two checks to determine if a point is inside or outside the projection area. Both checks rely on `projection.invert`.

The first is simple, don't drag the point unless `projection.invert([d3.event.x,d3.event.y])` is defined.

The second addresses projections such as orthographic projections. Since `projection.invert` always returns valid geographic points for these projections, we can the apply the forward projection to see if the svg point that is returned is equal to the svg point we started with. Essentially we want to drag the point when: `projection(projection.invert([x,y]) == [x,y]`. Since `projection.invert` is not one to one for these projections, this will not always be true.

To avoid potential rounding errors, I've expanded upon the comparison above (which unfortunately, requires breaking out the x and y components of the coordinates):

```
if ( 
   Math.abs(projection(projection.invert([d3.event.x,d3.event.y]))[0] - d3.event.x) < 0.5 
   && 
   Math.abs(projection(projection.invert([d3.event.x,d3.event.y]))[1] - d3.event.y) < 0.5) {     
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")");
}
```

Then we do both checks together, starting with the less demanding first check, and then doing the second check only if the first one checks out.

An updated [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ahrh9eLk/).

Comment: Indeed, I have been playing with the projection, but could not think of that trick...  Thank you very much ;)